# Bootstrap drop down menus not working on smart phones or tablets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got a problem with a Bootstrap site I've been working on. I'm not a bootstrap or javascript expert at all, I simply bought a theme and adapted it a little, expecting it to work at a basic level.

The bootstrap version in use is 2.2.1, and the problem is that drop down menus do not work properly on smart phones or tablets.

This is a sample site that demonstrates the problem: http://t879.nfshost.com/

When you click on the information menu, the drop down opens. When you click on any of the sub menu items (Our First Page, Our Second Page, etc.), it should open that page. On PCs and lap tops, this works correctly. On smart phones and tablets, the menu collapses and the new page is not opened.

This appears to be a known issue with bootstrap v 2.2.1, but none of the fixes I've found online (or here on Stackoverflow) seem to work or apply to the bootstrap files that came with the theme.

Any recommendations or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd just update to 2.3.2, rather than stick with that unsupported version.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and update your twitter bootstrap files to version 2.3.2 [here](http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/2.3.2/).

Make sure you're including both `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` and check the meta directive:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=no;"/>
```

Content should be a comma-delimited list.
Try to change that line with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and then read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to make changes based on what you want to achieve.